# Expression Tree Creation and ExpressionTree Convert Type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

lets say i have :

```
anything.where(x=>x.age == int.parse(txtage.text));
```

now i know that `int.parse(txtage.text)` is an expression of type ExpressionType.Convert

now i wanna know how to create an expression of type ExpressionType.Convert manually (programatically)

why ?

because im passing expressions between layers and changing the type of it , i managed make a visit to every expression and rebuild it except for

case ExpressionType.Convert:

any idea ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, `int.Parse(txtage.text)` is a method call, not a conversion expression. You'd build it using [`Expression.Call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341086.aspx).

However, if you *do* want to build a conversion expression, use [`Expression.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335409.aspx).

Comment: actually that lambda expression gets converted to x => (Convert(x.age) == Convert(Convert(Parse(value(type).ddlage.text))))

Comment: so i get it catched in case ExpressionType.Convert:

Comment: @Stacker: Well you haven't told us any of the types involved... is `x.age` not an int?

Comment: its int but still it needs to convert it for some reason

Comment: any way i managed to make Convert expression System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeUnary(ExpressionType.Convert, newoperand,type) now im trying to make call expression

Comment: @Stacker: If it's already an int, I wouldn't *expect* to see a convert call. Could you show a short but complete program demonstrating this? What type is it converting to?